# Highlight block of cells using conditional formatting - EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to highlight a block of cells using conditional formatting.

I'd like to specify a number, say 4, to highlight four rows of four cells, 16 cells total.

I'd like this to be dynamic so that I can change the number of cells from 4 to another value and still have the block colored accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cell A1 contains the number of columns and rows of the block to be formatted, create a conditional formatting rule with the following in cell B2:

```
=AND($A$1>=ROW(B2)-ROW($A$1),$A$1>=COLUMN(B2)-ROW($A$1))
```

Copy the rule to the maximum size of the block that can potentially be highlighted.

[image: 2x2 demo]

[image: 4x4 demo]